# Suggestions about books after assessing the level of English I stand at

Tags: discussion

Is there a website or something that would suggest me some books to read after assessing the level of English skills I have?

Comment: What have you read so far?

Comment: You want a website that evaluates your reading skills and recommends books based on that?

Comment: Most ELT publishers have graded readers. For example, the _Oxford Bookworms_ series has tests to determine which of the 7 levels you should start at: https://elt.oup.com/student/readersleveltest/?cc=de&selLanguage=de